# Probability that any player will receive any similar hand of the previous hand of any player?

Tags: poker-theory, probability

I want ask,  how to count this case? I understand that every deal of cards is a separate event, and does not depend on the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question to 100%, but the chance to receive any specific combination of cards (assumed we are talking about Texas Holdem) is `(1/52)*(1/51) => 0.04%`.

But in your question you are talking about "similar hand". So if you are talking about another player also getting Aces the chance would be:

`(4/52)*(3/51) => 0.45%`

Comment: Does it mean that if I have (e.g. Js 10h), then any player can get Js 10t in next hand with probability of 0.45% ?

Comment: If it's any combination of JT, then the chance is (4/52)*(4/51)=>0.6%, for a specific combination of suits it's (1/52)*(1/51)=0.04%.

Comment: Ok,  thanks a lot!